# Can't get rid of newlines

Tags: python, jinja2

I am passing a list of hosts to a jinja template, but it keeps rendering it with newline characters, i want them to all be on one line and just a space between them.

```
list_of_hosts = ['1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2','1.1.1.10','1.1.1.13','1.1.1.11','1.1.1.15']
```

Jinja template:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Hosts</td>
<td>
{% for host in hosts %}
    {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

I tried adding the "-" before and after the {{ host }} and it removes all spacing, so it combines everything together. Is there anyway to remove the newline characters and just have it on one line with just a space?

Comment: Try `{{ hosts | join(' ') }}` instead of your loop.

Comment: wow, perfect, exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: I added that as an answer. Feel free to accept if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ hosts | join(' ') }}` instead of your `for` loop.